# Floating point error in c++

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point

I have found a simple floating point error and I was wondering if there is a way around it. I'm compiling in Haiku OS.  I'm in Haiku r1 Alpha 4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float P(float PV, float r, int t){
  return(r * PV/1-pow((1+r),-t));
}

int main(void){
  float PV = 100000;
  float r = .005;
  int t = 350;

  std::cout << "A loan valued at $" << PV << " at a rate of %" << r << " with a payment period of " << t << "months would be $" << P(PV,r,t) << ", per-payment.\n";

  return 0;
}
```

When I run it `P(PV,r,t)` comes out as `499.834` it should be `500`. Though if I set `r = 0.06` `P` is correct and comes out as `P = 6000`.

Maybe it's a compiler error. I'm using gcc version 2.95.3-haiku-121101.

Comment: Read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) -- and then at least use `double`. For monetary calculations, the only correct way is *fixed point math* (use integers, define where your decimal point should be)

Comment: it comes out with the same output `499.834`, when I use `double P(float PV, float r, int t)`.

Comment: `PV/1` looks really really odd. Why do you divide through `1`? It does not alter the result.

Comment: @WhitequillRiclo, They meant to make it a double *before* losing accuracy from the calculation due to the more limited precision of float. I'd bet on the incorrect formula implementation before precision, though.

Comment: @mch: it's the formula for a loan payment: http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html

Comment: you're getting the formula incorrectly. It should be `r * PV/(1 - pow(1 + r, -t))`. Remember subtraction has lower precedence than division

Comment: Should it be `(r * PV/(1-pow((1+r),-t)))`?.By adding more braces can clarify the computation order.

Comment: The result should not be `500`, it should be `605.72`, accourding to the calculator at your link. When I add the missing parantheses, I get `605.718` as result.

Comment: I voted for duplicate before realizing the expression was also wrongly paranthesized. Anyways, doing this type of calculations in floating-point **is** a problem and the other one seems to be answered in comments....

Comment: Don't even bother thinking about compiler bugs at this level. The chances that you're going to find one is just way to low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
return(r * PV/1-pow((1+r),-t));
```

should be:

```
return(r * PV/(1-pow((1+r),-t)));
```

and the expected result is about 605.718, not 500.